After spring-boot update pom resolution failed
I updated the spring-boot version from 3.0.5 to 3.3.2. I am working with gradle 8.9
springBootVersion=3.3.2
dependencyManagementVersion=1.1.6

After that I sporadically get a lot of error messages that look like this:
Errors occurred while building effective model from C:\Users\<MY_USER>\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-dependencies\3.3.2\775c1cbdfb8f9bd6709801f86f1ba6262a9428ba\spring-boot-dependencies-3.3.2.pom:
'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.groupId' for ${project.groupId}:zipkin-reporter:jar with value '${project.groupId}' does not match a valid id pattern. in io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter-bom:3.4.0
'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.groupId' for ${project.groupId}:zipkin-sender-okhttp3:jar with value '${project.groupId}' does not match a valid id pattern. in io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter-bom:3.4.0
'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.groupId' for ${project.groupId}:zipkin-sender-libthrift:jar with value '${project.groupId}' does not match a valid id pattern. in io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter-bom:3.4.0
'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.groupId' for ${project.groupId}:zipkin-sender-urlconnection:jar with value '${project.groupId}' does not match a valid id pattern. in io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter-bom:3.4.0
'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.groupId' for ${project.groupId}:zipkin-sender-kafka:jar with value '${project.groupId}' does not match a valid id pattern. in io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter-bom:3.4.0
'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.groupId' for ${project.groupId}:zipkin-sender-amqp-client:jar with value '${project.groupId}' does not match a valid id pattern. in io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter-bom:3.4.0
'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.groupId' for ${project.groupId}:zipkin-sender-activemq-client:jar with value '${project.groupId}' does not match a valid id pattern. in io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter-bom:3.4.0
'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.groupId' for ${project.groupId}:zipkin-reporter-spring-beans:jar with value '${project.groupId}' does not match a valid id pattern. in io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter-bom:3.4.0
'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.groupId' for ${project.groupId}:zipkin-reporter-brave:jar with value '${project.groupId}' does not match a valid id pattern. in io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter-bom:3.4.0
'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.groupId' for ${project.groupId}:zipkin-reporter-metrics-micrometer:jar with value '${project.groupId}' does not match a valid id pattern. in io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter-bom:3.4.0
'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.groupId' for ${project.groupId}:brave:jar with value '${project.groupId}' does not match a valid id pattern. in io.zipkin.brave:brave-bom:6.0.3
'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.groupId' for ${project.groupId}:brave-tests:jar with value '${project.groupId}' does not match a valid id pattern. in io.zipkin.brave:brave-bom:6.0.3
'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.groupId' for ${project.groupId}:brave-context-jfr:jar with value '${project.groupId}' does not match a valid id pattern. in io.zipkin.brave:brave-bom:6.0.3
'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.groupId' for ${project.groupId}:brave-context-log4j2:jar with value '${project.groupId}' does not match a valid id pattern. in io.zipkin.brave:brave-bom:6.0.3
'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.groupId' for ${project.groupId}:brave-context-log4j12:jar with value '${project.groupId}' does not match a valid id pattern. in io.zipkin.brave:brave-bom:6.0.3
'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.groupId' for ${project.groupId}:brave-context-slf4j:jar with value '${project.groupId}' does not match a valid id pattern. in io.zipkin.brave:brave-bom:6.0.3

The corresponding POMs contain ${project.groupId} but I don't know how the resolution strategy works here.
The build continues to run somehow, but these messages are very confusing. Has anyone ever had a issue like this?
